# PHP - Exploding result query for associated tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two associated tables in my sql database. One is a list of airports named 'airports', the other is a list of airlines named 'airport_profiles'. The latter is the one I'd like to focus on. I associate the airline to the airport via an airport_id row. i.e the id number references the airport. My current PDO query is :

```
if(isset($_GET['airport'])) {

if ($_GET['airport'] == 1) { 
   $airportQuery = "SELECT * FROM airport_profiles";
   $airport = $db->prepare($airportQuery);
   $airport->execute();
}
else {
    $airportQuery = "SELECT * FROM airport_profiles WHERE airport_id = :airport_id";
    $airport = $db->prepare($airportQuery);
    $airport->execute(['airport_id' => $_GET['airport']]);
}   
$selectedAirport = $airport->fetchAll(); 

foreach ($selectedAirport as $profile) {        
    if ($profile['id'] == 1) continue;
```

I have tried inserting 
    `$profile = explode(';', $airport_id);`
But that isn't working at all.

Correct me if I'm wrong but from my understanding, in order to associate more than one airline to an airport I need to add an explode ';' to the query so that my airport_id's semicolon separated. Any advice would be greatly welcomed. 
Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is extremely hard to tell what you're asking about. Normally, explode has nothing to do with database queries at all. Can you please put aside that explode stuff and explain the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: Opps. My sincere apologies for the confusion. In short, I need to be able to associate more than one airline to an airport. By that, on the database side,  means adding more than one id, either comma or semicolon separated which in turn, provides more than one result which I am currently getting. From my understanding, that is down to the query.

Comment: you just add more rows to the airline table, that's all. they all already associated to an airport, thanks to airport_id field. no need anything else

Comment: Do you mean add a row for every airline? As that would end up quite a lot. The purpose of this is to have a 'select' dropdown with a populated list of airports. When an airport is selected it fetches the airlines that serve that particular airport.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Don't you *already* have a row for every airline? There is a table airlines that is supposedly to store the information about airlines, each in its distinct row. So I am genuinely confused.

Comment: Solved. Two things, one* being, as you very well stated I did have to add additional rows for each time I wanted to associate and airline with an airport, although in my mind that's no the most elegant solution. Two, I had to modify the query also, as I also displayed a 'show all'. Referring back to one* that meant I showed all of the airlines resulting in multiple times for the same airline. Picture easyjet 20 times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query changed to the following:

```
    if(isset($_GET['airport'])) {
        if ($_GET['airport'] == 1) {
            $airportQuery = "SELECT * FROM airport_profiles GROUP BY airline_name";
            $airport = $db->prepare($airportQuery);
            $airport->execute();
        }
else {
        $airportQuery = "SELECT * FROM airport_profiles WHERE airport_id = :airport_id";
        $airport = $db->prepare($airportQuery);
        $airport->execute(['airport_id' => $_GET['airport']]);
    }

    $selectedAirport = $airport->fetchAll();

        foreach ($selectedAirport as $profile) {
        if ($profile['id'] == 1) continue;
```